# What is bigger, $\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{24}$ or $\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{54}\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, roots, radicals

I have a math problem involving radicals. I tried to do it and I didn't find how to solve it.

> What is bigger, $\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{24}$ or $\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{54}\;$?

The answer can easily be found using a calculator, but I want a analytic solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing cubic factors from the cube roots

Comment: You should show your work and effort about what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hint: as $24=8\cdot3$ we have $\sqrt[3]{24}=2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Comment: I once gave my students a test question asking whether $41/29$ or $\sqrt{2}$ was larger.  It was surprising how many didn't think to square both numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to compare $a:=\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{24}$ and $b:=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{54}$. We have
$$a=\sqrt[3]{3}+2\sqrt[3]{3}=3\sqrt[3]{3}\quad\text{and}\quad b=\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt[3]{2}=4\sqrt[3]2.$$
Now $a^3=81$ and $b^3=128$. Hence $a<b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let,
$$x=\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{24}$$
$$y=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{54}$$
Our aim is to show that $y>x$.
Taking, $\sqrt[3]{3}$ common in x,
$$x=\sqrt[3]{3}(1+\sqrt[3]{8})=\sqrt[3]{3}(1+2)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{3}(3)=3^{\frac{1}{3}+1}=3^{\frac{4}{3}}$$
Taking $\sqrt[3]{2}$ common in y,
$$y=\sqrt[3]{2}(1+\sqrt[3]{27})=\sqrt[3]{2}(1+3)=       
 \sqrt[3]{2}(2^{2})=2^{\frac{1}{3}+2}=2^{\frac{7}{3}}$$
$$x=3^{\frac{4}{3}} y=2^{\frac{7}{3}}$$
$$x^{3}=3^{4} , y^{3}=2^{7}$$
$$\implies x^{3}<y^{3}$$
$$x<y$$
Hence proved.

Comment: This answer looks correct but lacks clarity.

Comment: Dhamnekar Winod, I have edited my answer and elaborated it. Hoping that it's much clear than previous time.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{24}<\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{54}$$

**Proof:-**

$\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{24}<\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{56}$

$(\sqrt[3]{3}(1+\sqrt[3]{8}))^3<(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{54})^3$

$81<56+3\sqrt[3]{216}+3\sqrt[3]{5832}$

$25<3×6×3×18$

$25<72$

**Q.E.D**